# Unable to use 'go to definition' option in VS Code v1.51.1 on Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

Trying to use 'go to definition' option in VS Code v1.51.1 on my Mac. But no luck. I couldn't jump to function definitions. I tried to update keybindings, checked with F12 and also with few keyboard shortcuts too. Also uninstalled & reinstalled. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: regarding your tags, visual-studio != visual-studio-code

Comment: what language are you working with?